# How to retrieve Javascript function value in webview component

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, dom-events

How can I retrieve the Javascript function value from a web page loaded withing a webview component??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, directly.

You can call the Javascript function via `loadUrl("javascript:...")`, where `...` is your function call. However, you cannot get a result this way.

If you inject a Java object into the Web page via `addJavascriptInterface()`, you could set up another function that called the function you want and returns that value via a call to the injected Java object. That only works if you can modify the Web page, though.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. could you share some sample code that uses the above concept. Im not really clear what its trying to do.
Thanks again in advance.