# Is it possible to run Javascript function in Android web page on webkit browser?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, webkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get the values of the fields in a form in an android webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547748/get-the-values-of-the-fields-in-a-form-in-an-android-webview-android)

I would like to get field data from a web page that is in an in-app browser.  Is it possible to call a javascript function from the browser and retrieve the data from the page?  Something similar to iOS' stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Yes it is.  I didn't use the correct words to find that answer.

Comment: I hope you don't feel like the "exact duplicate" thing is a criticism. This was a very different way of phrasing the question, so now somebody searching who thinks the same way as you can find your question and a pointer to the answer, so it's a good thing you asked.

Comment: No, I've been in the "biz" a long time and nomenclature changes all the time.  I'm happy that someone could translate my question so that I could find the good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547748/get-the-values-of-the-fields-in-a-form-in-an-android-webview-android) on basiclly the same situation.